# Speech-to-text with javascript in Chrome doesn't recognize anything

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I am trying to write a code in JAVASCRIPT which takes an input using voice and converts it into text and puts this text into textarea(HTML). My code is as shown below. The button appears kinda strange(smaller than usual) and when you click it, it doesnt work as desired. Please help.

My code is as follows:

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows=10 cols=80></textarea>
<button id="button" onclick="toggleStartStop()"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var recognizing;
var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
reset();
recognition.onend = reset();

recognition.onresult = function (event) {
  for (var i = resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
    if (event.results.final) {
      textarea.value += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    }
  }
}

function reset() {
  recognizing = false;
  button.innerHTML = "Click to Speak";
}

function toggleStartStop() {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    reset();
  } else {
    recognition.start();
    recognizing = true;
    button.innerHTML = "Click to Stop";
  }
}
```

Comment: "doesnt work as desired" isn't much of a description. You'll have to be more specific than that.

Comment: @Biffen when i click on the strange looking button and start speaking on the microphone it should convert my voice to text but it doesnt....i meaning nothing happens at all.

Comment: which browser you test ?

Comment: @mskimm i am using google chrome

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you are using some outdated sample code from the W3 site: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2012Oct/0032.html

Are you using Google Chrome? Open the JavaScript console, it should reveal this problem:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: SpeechRecognition is not defined

Here's a sample page that *does* work: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/demos/speech.html

It's all HTML5, so you can have a look at the entire source and learn from it. Have fun!

**EDIT:**
Minimum changes needed to make OP's code sample work on Google Chrome:

- replace `SpeechRecognition` by `webkitSpeechRecognition`
- replace `resultIndex` by `event.resultIndex`
- replace `event.results.final` by `event.results[i].isFinal`

Resulting code:

```
<textarea id="textarea" rows=10 cols=80></textarea>
<button id="button" onclick="toggleStartStop()"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
var recognizing;
var recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognition.continuous = true;
reset();
recognition.onend = reset();

recognition.onresult = function (event) {
  for (var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; ++i) {
    if (event.results[i].isFinal) {
      textarea.value += event.results[i][0].transcript;
    }
  }
}

function reset() {
  recognizing = false;
  button.innerHTML = "Click to Speak";
}

function toggleStartStop() {
  if (recognizing) {
    recognition.stop();
    reset();
  } else {
    recognition.start();
    recognizing = true;
    button.innerHTML = "Click to Stop";
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks..but they too have used javascript and my code is pretty much similar to theirs! :(

Comment: @user3510165: Except for the fact that Google's code _works_ and yours does not. You use class `SpeechRecognition`, Google use class `webkitSpeechRecognition`; apparently that's a relevant difference.

Comment: Oh i didnt realize it. Thank you. But now that i changed it and opened chrome using --allow-file-access-from-files method, the only difference is that the button appears normally and when i click it, i am asked the permission to use the microphone.
Once i allow it and start talking...then nothing appears in the textbox!!

Comment: @user3510165: There were more quirks in W3's code sample; see my edit above for the full list of fixes. Personally, I'd abandon that code and go for Google's. When somebody gives you a free Mercedes, you _drive_ it; you don't use it to harvest spare parts for your broken-down Nissan.

Comment: Working perfectly now. Thank you so much! Appreciate the help! :)

Comment: I'm using var recognition = new SpeechRecognition(); for android device but its not working.what can be the issue?